# How do I add a movable container to a WPF form?

Tags: wpf

WPF newbie so please be gentle.

Looking to rewrite an existing VFP app in C#/WPF

All forms have containers which in turn contain textboxes, labels, etc, etc.

Using this configuration allows the user to move the container and contained controls with the mouse, set up focal points within the container to enable zooming in and out of the form, etc.

So instead of adding controls directly to the WPF form, a movable container needs to be added first and the controls added to the container.

So where to begin?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) library to see if it can satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of the main things you're looking for is to add drag-and-drop ability for standard WPF panels/containers.  As Mash said, AvalonDock could be of use to you, especially if you're interested in docking the panels in certain positions.  But I would also suggest you taking a look at options to just add dragability to standard WPF panels.  This would be a lighter-weight option to get you started quickly, without having to worry about AvalonDock's constraints.

There are certainly many ways that you could implement drag-and-drop, but a very handy capability that I think is a good fit for this task is the concept of Attached "Behaviors".  Attached Behaviors basically allow you to "add on" capabilities to existing WPF controls without needing to alter or extend the actual control.  There are two basic types of attached behaviors.  One uses WPF Attached Properties, and the other uses what is commonly referred to as "Blend" behaviors.  If you just want to get started using a bahavior to solve your immediate problem, you don't necessarily need to understand all the nuances of these two approaches, but eventually you will probably find that both of these approaches have their place, so I'd suggest reading [**this post**](http://briannoyes.net/2012/12/20/AttachedBehaviorsVsAttachedPropertiesVsBlendBehaviors.aspx) about them.

In particular, there is a Blend behavior called [MouseDragElementBehavior](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html) that allows you to add drag-and-drop capability to WPF panels (the "e" and "d" here are xmlns namespace prefixes):

```
<Border Background="LightBlue" >
    <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:DragBehavior/>
    </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <TextBlock Text="Drag me around!" />
</Border>
```

In a similar vein, you mentioned zoomability, and there is [another Blend behavior](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/04/05/using-a-behavior-to-magnify-your-wpf-applications.aspx) that may be of use for you for that as well.

Blend behaviors are very easy to add an element if you're using Expression Blend, but you can also use them with Visual Studio.  To explain how to do this, see part of Laurent's post about his [magnify behavior](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/04/05/using-a-behavior-to-magnify-your-wpf-applications.aspx).